# Parse Cloud code: How to modify authData column on a User?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been trying to implement 'Login via Facebook' functionality in my application. I'm using Parse as backend. The problem arises due to the fact that Parse creates a new entry in the User Table with authData and random username, even if there's already a user exists with the same email in the User Table. So what I'm doing for now is ask user to connect Facebook via Facebook SDK, and get his email. Then I call this cloud code from Android that will search the user associated with that email in the Parse User Table. If a user exists, I'm trying to update the authData field. It can update any column but authData. It gives the following error while updating authData from cloud code.

`Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object`

Following is the cloud code I'm using:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("facebookLogin", function(request, response){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var email = request.params.email;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo("email", email);
    userQuery.first({
        success: function(user) {           
            if (user) {         
                Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
                var authData = util.createFBAuthData(request.params.id, request.params.access_token, request.params.expiration_date);
                console.log(authData);
                user.set("authData", authData);
                user.save(null, {
                    success: function(rest) {
                        response.success(rest);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        response.error(messageLog.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                }); 
            } else {

                createNewUserEntry(request);
            }
        }, 
        error: function() {
            response.error(messageLog.getErrorMessage());
        }
    });
})
```

I don't understand why Parse isn't allowing to edit/update authData using cloud code. I'm able to manually insert (Copy/Paste) the json into the authData field in the User Table from the Parse Dashboard. Anybody who has faced this issue?

Comment: how did you get around this?